# Rest Api with Spring Security 3.1.1 and OAuth2 - org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, security, oauth-2.0

Recently I was given this task to update from OAuth1 to OAuth2.
It's a Spring MVC app secured with Spring Security. For both the version is 3.1.1.RELEASE. The OAuth2 version is 1.0.5.RELEASE.

I made a demo project with just one user defined inplace, and everything si working as expected. I used Postman from Chrome to make the requests.

When I merged the app to this new securityContext.xml, something strange is happening :

- I make the first request (with the username and the password), the app connects to the DB, finds the user, and returns the refresh token;
- The second request to get the access_token (now I send the refresh token).
- Third request to the get some actual data from DB, I send the access_token, but then I get this exception :  `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread .`

The problem occurs when : (2nd time)

```
this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

The thing is, with the first request, when the app searches for the user in DB, I get no such exception. Only the second call fails (3rd request). If I would open a new session `this.getSessionFactory().openSession()` , everything would work just fine. But then I would have to do some hacks which I wouldn't want to.

The UserDetailsServiceImpl class looks like this:

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws...
    { }
}
```

In the securityContext there is a transaction manager already declared.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Each Service interface is annotated with `@Transactional` . 
Everything was fine until the migration to OAuth2.

Any ideas ?
I would really much appreciate it.
If someone asks, I can provide the other xml files.

securityContext.xml file :

```
       <!-- 
            Requests examples :

                1   -               http://localhost:8080/SillyService/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=admin&password=admin
                2   -               http://localhost:8080/SillyService/oauth/token?client_id=my-trusted-client&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=

                3.1 - example :     http://localhost:8080/SillyService/employee/1?access_token=
                3.2 - example :     http://localhost:8080/SillyService/leagues?access_token=
        -->

         <!-- 
            Requests examples :

                1   -               http://localhost:8080/vra-service/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=admin&password=admin
                2   -               http://localhost:8080/vra-service/oauth/token?client_id=my-trusted-client&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=

                3.1 - example :     http://localhost:8080/vra-service/employee/1?access_token=
                3.2 - example :     http://localhost:8080/vra-service/leagues?access_token=
        -->

    <!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
    <http   pattern="/oauth/token" 
            create-session="stateless"
            authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ -->
    <!-- DEMO PURPOSE ONLY -->
    <!-- ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ -->

    <http   pattern="/employee/**" 
            create-session="never"
            entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
            auto-config="true" 
            use-expressions="true"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />

        <!-- 
            ***********************
            * Protected resources *
            ***********************
         --> 

        <intercept-url pattern="/employee/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
    </http>

    <!-- ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ -->
    <!-- ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ -->

    <http   pattern="/**" 
            create-session="never"
            entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
            auto-config="true" 
            use-expressions="true"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />

        <!-- 
            ***********************
            * Protected resources *
            ***********************
         --> 

        <intercept-url pattern="/properties/**"                 method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/health/**"                     method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/listThreads/**"                method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/cfListProperties/**"           method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/quartzList/**"                 method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/quartzListTriggers/**"         method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/listFailedRaces/**"            method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/listFailedMatches/**"          method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/sportsfeedlistsubscribers/**"  method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/mcGetMatchCards/**"            method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/sfEnableSubscriber/**"         method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>   
        <intercept-url pattern="/sfDisableSubscriber/**"        method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/sfUpdateSubscriber/**"         method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/sfAddSubscriber/**"            method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/sfListSubscriber/**"           method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/titles/**"                     method="GET"        access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/titles/**"                     method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/titles/**"                     method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/sportsfeedconfigs/**"          method="GET"        access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/sportsfeedconfigs/**"          method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/sportsfeedconfigs/**"          method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/schedules/**"                  method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/schedules/**"                  method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/schedules/**"                  method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/races/**"                      method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/raceconfigs/**"                method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/raceconfigs/**"                method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/raceconfigs/**"                method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses/**"                    method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/competitors/**"                method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/competitors/**"                method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/competitors/**"                method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/competitors/**"                method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/teams/**"                      method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/sportsfeedfailures/**"         method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>   
        <intercept-url pattern="/userentities/name/**"          method="GET"        access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/userentities/**"               method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/userentities/**"               method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/userentities/**"               method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/userentities/**"               method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/userroles/**"                  method="GET"        access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/alerts/**"                     method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/alerts/**"                     method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/alerts/**"                     method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/alerts/**"                     method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/meetingtimes/**"               method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/meetingtimes/**"               method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/meetingtimes/**"               method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/meetingtimes/**"               method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/matches/**"                    method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchcompetitors/**"           method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchcompetitors/**"           method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchcompetitors/**"           method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchcompetitors/**"           method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchteams/**"                 method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchteams/**"                 method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchteams/**"                 method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchteams/**"                 method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/leagues/**"                    method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/leagues/**"                    method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/leagues/**"                    method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/leagues/**"                    method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/grounds/**"                    method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/grounds/**"                    method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/grounds/**"                    method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/grounds/**"                    method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/configpropcomponents/**"       method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/configpropcomponents/**"       method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/configpropcomponents/**"       method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/configpropcomponents/**"       method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/configprops/**"                method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/configprops/**"                method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/configprops/**"                method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/configprops/**"                method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses/**"                    method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses/**"                    method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses/**"                    method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses/**"                    method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchInterval/**"              method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/matchfeedfailures/**"          method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/groupschedules/**"             method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/groupschedules/**"             method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/groupschedules/**"             method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/groupschedules/**"             method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopdetails/**"                method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopdetails/**"                method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopdetails/**"                method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopdetails/**"                method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopgroup/**"                  method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_READER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopgroup/**"                  method="PUT"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopgroup/**"                  method="POST"       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopgroup/**"                  method="DELETE"     access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shopgroupconfig/**"            method="GET"        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
    </http>

    <!-- 
        If you aren't using form login, OpenID or basic authentication through the namespace, you may want to define an authentication 
        filter and entry point using a traditional bean syntax and link them into the namespace, as we've just seen. The corresponding 
        AuthenticationEntryPoint can be set using the entry-point-ref attribute on the <http> element.
     -->
    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="dstest" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        By default, the BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint provisioned by Spring Security returns a full page for a 401 Unauthorized 
        response back to the client. This HTML representation of the error renders well in a browser, but it's not well suited 
        for other scenarios, such as a REST API where a json representation may be preferred. The namespace is flexible enough 
        for this new requirement as well – to address this – the entry point can be overridden: 
     -->
    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        If authorization fails and the caller has asked for a specific content type response, this entry point can send one, along 
        with a standard 403 status. Add to the Spring Security configuration as an {@link AccessDeniedHandler} in the usual way.
     -->
    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <!-- 
        A filter and authentication endpoint for the OAuth2 Token Endpoint. Allows clients to authenticate using request parameters 
        if included as a security filter, as permitted by the specification (but not recommended). It is recommended by the 
        specification that you permit HTTP basic authentication for clients, and not use this filter at all.
     -->
    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        Makes a final access control (authorization) decision.
     -->
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ -->
    <!-- ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ -->

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                <salt-source ref="saltSource" />
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ -->
    <!-- ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ -->

    <!-- 
        For hashing user passwords 
    --> 
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        For salting user passwords 
    -->
    <bean id="saltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource" p:userPropertyToUse="username" />

    <!-- 
        OAuth specific - loads user-specific data.
     -->
    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        Token Store - Implementation of token services that stores tokens in memory.
    -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <!--
        Base implementation for token services using random UUID values for the access token and refresh token values. The
        main extension point for customizations is the {@link TokenEnhancer} which will be called after the access and refresh 
        tokens have been generated but before they are stored. Persistence is delegated to a {@code TokenStore} implementation 
        and customization of the access token to a {@link TokenEnhancer}.
     -->
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        <!-- VIV -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        A user approval handler that remembers approval decisions by consulting existing tokens. 
    -->
    <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        Token management 
    -->
    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" 
                                token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                                user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <!-- 
        The resource server is the OAuth 2.0 term for your API server. The resource server handles authenticated requests after the 
        application has obtained an access token.
    -->
    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="dstest" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <!-- 
        OAuth Client Definition - A service that provides the details about an OAuth2 client. 
    -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client   client-id="my-trusted-client"
                        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
                        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" 
                        redirect-uri="/web"
                        scope="read,write,trust" 
                        access-token-validity="30"
                        refresh-token-validity="600" />
    </oauth:client-details-service>


    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Do you have more spring config? How is `txManager` defined? You can try using `@Transactional(transactionManager = "txManager")`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The hibernate context wasn't visible from the dispatcher-servlet context.
Added this line in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<import resource="hibernateDataAccessContext.xml" />
```

More info here :

```
https://www.dotkam.com/2008/07/09/spring-web-application-context-visibility/
```